# Как быстро docker запускает контейнер

Tags: docker, time-complexity

Я хочу создавать контейнеры на лету в node js, и возращать ответ. Меня интерисует скорость создания и удаления контейнера и также количесво памяти в это время. Как долго контейнер работает я знаю:).

Comment: `$ time команда`